# How can I serve a file based on a parameter in Dream?

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a simple Dream application that will handle routing by simply serving an HTML file associated with the route parameter.

I tried doing it with this code:

```ml
let serve_file dir request =
  Dream.from_filesystem dir ((Dream.param request "file") ^ ".html")

let () =
  Dream.run
  @@ Dream.logger
  @@ Dream.router [
    Dream.get "/" (Dream.from_filesystem "html" "index.html");
    Dream.get "/:file" (serve_file "html")
  ]
```

I am not sure why this isn't working, I get a type error that stumps me even more as well:

```
This expression has type Dream.request -> Dream.handler, but an expression was expected of 
type: Dream.handler = Dream.request -> Dream.response Lwt.t
```

How can this be the case when the first `get` is accepting `(Dream.from_filesystem)`?

Comment: Not a solution but a style suggestion: `Dream.from_filesystem dir ((Dream.param request "file") ^ ".html")` contains too many parens. You should be able to write `Dream.from_filesystem dir (Dream.param request "file" ^ ".html")` or even `Dream.from_filesystem dir @@ Dream.param request "file" ^ ".html"`

Comment: @Chris I want to append `".html"` to the result of the `Dream.param request "file"`, I'm not sure if your suggestion works.

Comment: It does. Operator precedence is tricky. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the `request` to the `from_filesystem` handler when defining the `serve_file` handler:

```
let serve_file dir request =
  Dream.from_filesystem
    dir
    (Dream.param request "file" ^ ".html") 
    request
```